# JavaScript regex to get first alphabet of max 3 words of a Persian / English string

Tags: javascript, regex

[image]I have the following strings in Persian, and English.

1-   گروه جوانان خلاق

2- (نی (حمایت کننده رسانه های آزاد افغانستان

3- نی | حمایت کننده رسانه های آزاد افغانستان

4- NKCC    (Nawi Kunduz Construction Company)

5- Afghanistan Development And Registry Services

What I want to do is get first alphabet of max 3 word of each sentence.
What I have tried:

```
\b(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9])|(?:[\u0621-\u0628\u062A-\u063A\u0641-\u0642\u0644-\u0648\u064E-\u0651\u0655\u067E\u0686\u0698\u06A9\u06AF\u06BE\u06CC]))
```

Above regex only work for English sentence, my main problem is with `\b` for Persian sentence, and force to consider only max 3 word.

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/uzIRZa/1 (note that highlighting Arabic is broken there, just have a look at the MATCH pane on the right)

Comment: Also, see https://jsfiddle.net/74ufn709/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it returns `)`, but I need only alphabet

Comment: No, it does not "return" `)`. You only need Group 1 value.  See https://jsfiddle.net/74ufn709/

Comment: So, does the code demo work for you, or please let know what is wrong there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So how we can match only max 3 word ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for me your regex problem is with word boundary, for example if a word contain none alphabet characters like `adfds-ds-dfs` it take it as 3 word, and also for those words that is like `NKCC (Nawi Kunduz Construction Company)` it return `['N', '(N', 'K', 'K', 'C', 'C']`

Comment: What do you mean by "max 3 word"? In my snippet, no `(` is returned together with `N`. I do not know what code you are using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My purpose is if a sentence has more than 3 word, so get first alphabet of its first 3 word.

Comment: And if there are 1, 2 or 3 words only? Return nothing?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, for less than 3 word it should return first alphabet of all words, now check my question, I have attached your answer

Comment: You have included a screenshot of regex101 test, it looks ugly. Anyway, as I said, Group 1 is all you need. And to get the first 3 you may just slice the resulting array. Or limit its population when creating. See [**`this demo`**](https://jsfiddle.net/74ufn709/2/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build a regex that first matches start of string or any char other than a word (letters and digits) char, and then capture the first letter/digit, but only collect the first 3 matches:

```js
var strs = ["|گروه جوانان خلاق", "(نی (حمایت کننده رسانه های آزاد افغانستان", "نی | حمایت کننده رسانه های آزاد افغانستان", "NKCC (Nawi Kunduz Construction Company)","5- Afghanistan Development And Registry Services"];
var pblock = "\\u0621-\\u0628\\u062A-\\u063A\\u0641-\\u0642\\u0644-\\u0648\\u064E-\\u0651\\u0655\\u067E\\u0686\\u0698\\u06A9\\u06AF\\u06BE\\u06CC";
var rx = new RegExp("(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9" + pblock + "])([a-zA-Z0-9" + pblock + "])", "g");
for (var s of strs) {
  var m, cnt=0, res=[];
  while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
    if (cnt < 3) {
    res.push(m[1]);
      cnt++;
    } else break;
  }
  console.log(s, res);
  
}
```